How to merge attributes in Layered Navigation?
I am working on a project in which one of the categories has 19K products and brand attributes for these products have 2K options. My problem is that if I divide it into multiple attributes, then parent categories will show multiple brand attributes in Layered Navigation.
I want to know the best, most feasible, and fastest solution for this problem.
